# Gilead and GWT integration

Tags: hibernate, gwt, gilead

this is the second time I am posting this on stack overflow forum, the first
time i didn't got any reply, this time I suppose that someone might
help me. My problem is that I am not being able to integrate gilead
with gwt.

I am getting a series of problem sometimes log problem, persistence
errors. Has someone try the music store tutorial by google, this is
not launching at my place.

Can some explain me how to integrate gilead into gwt by giving precise
steps that worked for them and if possible send me the jars they have
used at my mail bakenoor@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you follow the tutorial at http://noon.gilead.free.fr/gilead/index.php?page=doc in a brand new project and try to get that working, if you cannot you can post the specific errors and issues you're running into.

Comment: Hi, is it necessary to use spring when trying to integrate Gilead with GWT??

Comment: I use Gilead without Spring, so yes.